# Memory Management C and free() of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

so I have some questions on how to do correct memory management.

Basically my question is, what happens when for example I take this code(shown below). Does this need to be freed to prevent memory leaks?

```
    void traverseLeftRight(struct node *head){

        current = head;

        if(current == NULL){

            printf("There are no nodes within the list\n");
        }

        while(1){

            if(current != NULL){

                printf("left to right output:           %d\n", current -> value);
                current = current -> next;
            }else{

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, would free(current) and current = NULL break the list if i were do it within the break section of the list. Also, would something like this just break the pointing variable and not effect the node that it corresponds to?

```
void traverseLeftRight(struct node *head){

    current = head;

    if(current == NULL){

        printf("There are no nodes within the list\n");
    }

    while(1){

        if(current != NULL){

            printf("left to right output:           %d\n", current -> value);
            current = current -> next;
        }else{

            free(current);
            current = NULL;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every allocation should be paired with exactly one free, performed after the allocated space is no longer needed.  Merely *accessing* allocated memory does not incur any additional obligation.

Comment: As for your proposed variation on the code, it is absolutely pointless.  The `else` block is entered only when `current` evaluates to `NULL` already.  Freeing it or redundantly setting it to `NULL` is not useful.

Comment: Okay thank you, what i originally thought for what happened when i use something like current is that i would need to free the value that i used for it.

Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: So just to be clear, i would only ever free when i am currently deleting a node from the list that i am using since that is what is requiring the allocation or at the end of the program? Then no where else unless specified by a c library function (in general terms)?

Comment: Yes, when you are removing a dynamically-allocated node from the list is a natural time to free its memory, and you must not under any circumstances free its memory while it remains *in* the list.  Details would need to refer to specific code.

Comment: you haven't mentioned a type for `current`. unless its a global variable you should declare as `struct node *current = head;`.

Comment: `current` becomes a local variable, which you are using only to **traverse** through pointers (**in the above case only to print data in the nodes**). As soon as the function returns , this variable is no longer available. `free` is in appropriate here.

Comment: And yes i am using this as a global variable for current. since i am separating each set of functions into a library and initializing these variables within the header.

Comment: Which i did not mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about memory management.

In the examples you've shown, there's no need for any freeing, because nothing has (as far as we can see) been allocated.

If you allocate memory with malloc(3) or friends, then you will typically need to free it later, *exactly once*.  In general, failing to free something leaks memory (ie, the memory is still allocated, but you're not pointing to it any more, so can't use it), and freeing more than once is an error (in the sense that this opens the possibility of two bits of the code both believing they've been allocated exclusive use of the same bit of memory).  Using a bit of memory (ie, dereferencing a pointer) after it's been freed is the classic ‘use-after-free’ error.  Each of these results in somewhat hard-to-find bugs (but [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is your friend).

The call to `free` in your second would (unfortunately) not cause an error, because `free` doesn't report such errors.

You don't need to free memory if it's in use all the way to the end of the program – that's (in effect) freed automatically when the program finishes.

Almost the only case where you'd call `free` within a function like this is if you were writing a function to walk along a linked list (or something like that), freeing as it went.  A traverse of a list (as your function name suggests) would not be expected to result in the list being freed.

Comment: Okay, i guess i have not heard of the term "walking". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Walking along a list is what you're doing in that function: stepping from one linked-list item to another, by `current = current->next` (think stepping-stones, perhaps).

Comment: There is no error related to the call to `free()` in the second code.  It is not erroneous to pass a null pointer to `free()`; doing so is well defined to have no effect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ooops: true enough – I hadn't noticed that it was guaranteed to be NULL in that branch. What I was getting at was that `free` (possibly unfortunately) doesn't signal errors in any way, even when it's given a non-allocated non-NULL argument (POSIX says the behaviour is undefined in that case (but it's unlikely to be good)).

Comment: @johnBollinger as far as free() and then into a Null assignment is the proper way to free a variable according to my professor. He says this because it is more secure doing it that way since whomever that may have I'll intent can still access the inforation that was used until it is changed since it is pointing to that memory location, but can't if it is change to a null pointing variable.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen Yes, that's true in general, but in this case you're doing the `free` in the branch where `current` is _already_ null – that is, in the branch where there is nothing to free.  Do you perhaps mean the `free` to be in the other branch? This is supposing that the purpose of this function is to traverse the linked list, freeing as you go. Perhaps you need a ‘this function will...’ purpose comment at the top of this function...!

Comment: I was just confused about what i had to free if anything. I say this because i thought i had to free a temp pointer within the function to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen Aha! We may have got to the source of your confusion. When you allocate memory with `malloc`, the system reserves a block of RAM for your use, and gives you a pointer to it (eg, `struct node* my_ptr`). You can pass that pointer around, including assigning it to other `struct node*`, or passing it to functions, but when you're finished with it, possibly much later, you have to tell the system you don't need it any more (with `free`). But you free the _memory_, not the _pointer_ to it. [Variables _within a function_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) are different.

Answer (score 0):

here is your first code, corrected, so an empty list does not enter the 'while()' loop

```
void traverseLeftRight(struct node *head)
{

    current = head;

    if(current == NULL)
    { // then list empty
        printf("There are no nodes within the list\n");
    }

    while( current != NULL )
    { // then, another node to print
        printf("left to right output:           %d\n", current -> value);
        current = current->next;   // step to next node in list
    }
}
```

here is your second code, with comments

```
while(1)
{

    if(current != NULL)
    { // then, not at end of list
        printf("left to right output:           %d\n", current -> value);
        current = current->next;  // step to next entry in list
    }

    else
    { // else, current == NULL ,, I.E. past end of list

        free(current);    // nothing will happen because Current == NULL
        current = NULL;   // already NULL, so nothing will change
        break;            // exit the 'while()' loop
    }
}
```

proposed code that free's the linked list as it traverses it.

Note that the 'head' needs to be updated as the list is 'free'd

```
// note the 'pointer to pointer parameter, so 'head' can be modified
void traverseLeftRight(struct node **head)  
{
    if( *head == NULL)
    {  // then, list is empty
        printf("There are no nodes within the list\n");
    }

    while( *head != NULL)
    { // while another node to process
        struct node *temp = *head; // remember current node pointer
        printf("left to right output:           %d\n", current -> value);
        *head = (*head)->next;     // step to next node
        free( temp );              // eliminate current node
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, in regards to the code for the traversing. I do not have it mentioned in here but each of these sets of functions are used with a header, so i am not initializing the current within these (I just use current because it is easier for me to understand).

Comment: Also, this code is not to actually free the code, this is just to give the corresponding value for each of the nodes within the list. I have a different function that is not a part of this to do that.

Comment: should not declare variables in header files. (although data types can be defined in header files.)

Comment: @JeffreyHennen, the posted code calls `free()` on the nodes, so my proposed answer calls `free()` on the nodes.  Please state questions so such misunderstandings are avoided.